# Dirty redirects in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

text/x-generic .htaccess ( UTF-8 Unicode text )

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

One of my optimization tools indicates that I've multiple redirects for www (HTTP), which is HTTP to HTTPS and once again HTTPS TO HTTPS. How do I fix this?

[image: 2 redirects reported by optimization tool]

Comment: "HTTP to HTTPS and once again HTTPS TO HTTP" - Really? That isn't just "multiple redirects", that is a _redirect loop_ and your site won't work at all? (An HTTPS to HTTP redirect is not caused by your current `.htaccess` file. If this is what you are seeing then it's probably in your web application.)

Comment: @MrWhite My bad. There was a typo. It actually says HTTPS to HTTPS, not HTTPS to HTTP.

Comment: @MrWhite https://i.imgur.com/nR5D1qz.png This might provide some clarity I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...which is HTTP to HTTPS and once again HTTPS TO HTTPS

Specifically, from your screenshot, you are seeing two redirects when requesting HTTP and www (ie. `http://www.example.com`):

1. `http://www.example.com` to `https://www.example.com` (HTTP to HTTPS)
2. `https://www.example.com` to `https://example.com` (www to non-www)

No.1 is triggered by your `.htaccess` rule and no.2 is no doubt being triggered by WordPress itself in PHP.

This series of redirects is actually required if you ever plan to implement [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) (despite what your "optimization tool" is reporting).

Otherwise, you can avoid the double redirect by canonicalising the hostname in `.htaccess`, *before* WordPress does it. One way is to add an additional rule *before* your existing HTTP to HTTPS redirect. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

# www to non-www (and HTTPS)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([a-z.]+?)\.?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]   

# HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The `%1` in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* is a backreference to the first captured group in the last matched *CondPattern*. In other words, the hostname less any `www.` prefix (and any trailing dot, in the case of a FQDN).

Note that the www to non-www redirect also redirects to HTTPS. So this ensures the following HTTP to HTTPS is never processed when the first redirect occurs (so no 2nd redirect).

Make sure you clear your browser cache before testing. (To avoid caching issues it is often preferable to first test with 302 - temporary- redirects.)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem you should remove `www` from `{HTTP_HOST}`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

should be changed to

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([a-z.]+)$ [NC]<br>
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Your suggested code snippet doesn't "remove `www`" as you suggest (you need to use a backreference to the matched _CondPattern_ instead of repeating the `HTTP_HOST` server variable in the _substitution_), but neither would this redirect `http://example.com` to HTTPS - which I'm sure is the intention.

Comment: @MrWhite True. Agree with you.